# Most efficient way to backup user preferences on MySQL Database in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

I am working on a website where user clicks on a add buttons to get information about that topic. Currently, when user clicks on any add button i store the data in a cookie. For example,

Let's say the Topics are A, B, C, D and so on.

I store them in a cookie like - A,B,X,P,Z. In other words as a comma separated list. What I want to do is backup the preferences on server in a database. This way if the user clears cookies sometime i still have the data backed up. Also, the user will be able to login on other devices with same preferences.

If I connect to the database on every user click, I will hit the concurrent maximum connections list probably. Is there some way to do it efficiently?

Is there some other option altogether? I am looking for something like feedly where user clicks on add button and the preferences are saved.

Comment: back them up periodically, then, or only when the user CHANGES the prefs. there's no point in continually sending over "save everything, because nothing's changed". you only have to do "save this, because user changed X".

Comment: You could store it browser-side in [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) rather than cookies, then you wouldn't have to worry about the user clearing cookies (yes, they could also clear local storage, but users do that less often than cookies).